# Adding add_action function

Tags: actions

How does this hook work? I need to insert an action into a page specified within the `wp_head()` or `wp_footer()` function.

But when you add the action in `wp_head` (`add_action ( 'wp_head', 'mymail_change_list_segment');`), the variables in question are empty or the whole thing's not working.

So I added my function to the `header.php` and `footer.php` and it still doesn't work.

When I put it directly into `page.php`, it works.

Can someone help me?

```
add_action('wp_head','mymail_change_list_segment');
function mymail_change_list_segment() {
    if ( is_page(711) ) {
        $userhash = isset($_COOKIE['mymail']) ? $_COOKIE['mymail'] : NULL;
        $subscriber = mymail('subscribers')->get_by_hash($userhash, true);
        $user_mail = $subscriber->email;
        $lists = 1;
        global $user_mail, $userhash, $lists, $subscriber;
        $subscriber_ids = mymail('subscribers')->add(array(
            'email' => $user_mail,
            'status' => 1,
        ), $overwrite = true );
        mymail('subscribers')->assign_lists($subscriber_ids, $lists, $remove_old = true);
    }}
```

Comment: The proper place would be the functions.php, but which variables are empty? $_COOKIE?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is ensure that your template's `header.php` and `footer.php` files contain, respectively, calls to [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer). Without those functions, no actions hooked to `wp_head` / `wp_footer` will work.